# IntelliJ Cannot find module with '@' symbol

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, node-modules

I am using IntelliJ for web development.  In my typescript file, I am importin a node module that's named with a preceding '@' symbol.  The code works and all.  But I find it annoying that IntelliJ makes the import statement as an error.  It says: `Cannot find module '@example/package'`

Anybody know a fix for this?  The OCD in me wants to make sure that there are no red lines in my IDE.  Again, the code works.  It compiles.  The site runs without errors.

John.

Comment: This is an IntelliJ error right? (i.e. not preceded by TSXXXX) I'd suggest disabling the inspection and relying on the TS language service errors, which are far more accurate.

Comment: IDEA doesn't have problems resolving scoped packages. Is this module included in project (i.e. check if the corresponding folder is marked as excluded)? What IDEA version do you work with?

Comment: Thanks Lena.  My module is inside my node_modules directory.  It's normal to exclude that folder from the project, isn't it?